# Inserting new name in field mysql with temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a duplicate functionality in my application, this duplicates an entire vacancy with the following code, in the example i am duplicating from vacancy id 94 (which has banner name "image.jpg":

```
$vacdata = $this->vacancies_model->get($data['old_vacancy_id']);
$newvacbannername = return_unique_filename($vacdata->banner);
copy_file($vacdata->banner, $newvacbannername);
$data['newvacancyid'] = $this->vacancies_model->duplicate($data['old_vacancy_id'], $newvacbannername);
```

In the $newvacbannername there is the string "image_8.jpg". Which is the unique name of my new file name which i copy, the copy is working as intended.

The function duplicate looks like this:

```
function duplicate($vacid, $banner)
{
    $this->db->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE vacancy_id = ' . $vacid);
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET vacancy_id = NULL');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET banner = ' . $banner );
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET create_time = now()');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET watch_counter = 0');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET contact_info_counter = 0');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET status = 0');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET reminder_mail_sent = 0');
    $this->db->query('UPDATE tmptable SET extend_code = NULL');
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO vacancies SELECT * FROM tmptable');
    $newvacancyid = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->query('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable');
    return $newvacancyid;
}
```

I tried doing a var_dump on $banner to make sure that this variable contains the correct string, and it does contain image_8.jpg. So it just copies the banner from the original vacancy but it does not set the new banner name

If i look at the SQL that was executed i see the following results:

> 0.0076    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE vacancy_id = 94
>
> 0.0090    UPDATE tmptable SET vacancy_id = NULL
>
> 0.0000    UPDATE tmptable SET banner = image_8.jpg
>
> 0.0005    UPDATE tmptable SET create_time = now()
>
> 0.0023    UPDATE tmptable SET watch_counter = 0
>
> 0.0001    UPDATE tmptable SET contact_info_counter = 0
>
> 0.0002    UPDATE tmptable SET status = 0
>
> 0.0002    UPDATE tmptable SET reminder_mail_sent = 0
>
> 0.0002    UPDATE tmptable SET extend_code = NULL
>
> 0.0153    INSERT INTO vacancies SELECT * FROM tmptable

However if i look in mysql itself for the new vacancy duplicated, the row it inserted everything in the update statement works except for the $banner, it inserted the exact same name as in the original vacancy (image.jpg in this example instead of image_8.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
INSERT INTO vacancies
    SELECT
    NULL, --id field
    other_columns,
    go_here,
    NULL,
    :banner, --bind this from $banner,
    now(),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    NULL
    FROM vacancies
    WHERE vacancy_id = ' . $vacid
```

Seems like a stretch to involve a temporary table, and a ton of queries, when you can simply do this in one. Also: Look into **binding** variables to your query: It's much safer, and the recommend approach.

Alternatively, you can also do this via a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

```
INSERT INTO vacancies
SELECT
*
FROM vacancies
WHERE vacancy_id = :vacid;
```

```
UPDATE vacancies
SET banner = :banner,
create_time = now(),
watch_counter = 0,
...
WHERE vacancy_id = :vacid --Get the inserted ID from mysql_insert_id();
```

```
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it a performance issue to use this many queries as i am doing now (with the temp table)?

Comment: You could just simply do all the UPDATEs at least in one query.